# Looking for a software to compute recurrence relation

Tags: scientific-computing

I have the following recurrence relation:
x(1)=1$, x(2)=t and x(n+2)=(t*x(n-1)-d^(n-3)*x(n))/d^n

where t and d are variables and n is any natural number.

When we assign values to n we obtain rational functions in terms of t and d.

I would like to use a software that shows me the first 50 rational functions, i.e. x(3), x(4),..., x(50).

The problem is I do not know any software that can do this for me.
Do you know one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope I understand your request right. What you are searching for is a program which computes recursively defined functions **symbolic**.

A lot of **professional mathemtical software** exists which can handle your task, like

- Matlab
- Maple
- Mathematica

If you prefer free software as I do use

- **Python** with the [**SymPy**](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) package
- Octave
- Sage